# Application hangs using WMI to read the current CPU ClockSpeed

Tags: c#, winforms, wmi, backgroundworker

I started with a basic Winforms application to get the current CPU clockspeed every three seconds and refresh a Label with the value retrieved.

At first I used a threaded Timer, but I read it was 'bad practice' because it consumes a Thread. So, I used the BackgroundWorker class to do the job.  Unfortunately, the program still freezes every three seconds.

Hereby some code fragments:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        GenerateDelay(3000);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    GetCurrentCpuSpeed();
}

private void GetCurrentCpuSpeed()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");

    foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get()) {
        var clockSpeed = obj["CurrentClockSpeed"].ToString();
        lblCurrentClockSpeed.Text = clockSpeed;
    }
}

private void GenerateDelay(int miliseconds)
{
    Thread.Sleep(miliseconds);
}
```

I've also tried this method as a variation:

```
private void GetCurrentCpuClockSpeed()
{
    using (ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("win32_processor"))
    {
        var instances = mc.GetInstances();

        foreach (var item in instances) {
            try {
                lblCurrentClockSpeed.Text = item.Properties["CurrentClockSpeed"].Value.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: based on the comments changed the code to use a Timer. Deleted my 'answer post'.

Here are some code fragments:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateAndStartTimer();
}

private void CreateAndStartTimer()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    t.Interval = 3000;
    t.Tick += new EventHandler(GetCurrentCpuSpeed2);
    t.Start();
}

private void GetCurrentCpuSpeed2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");

    foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get()) {
        var clockSpeed = obj["CurrentClockSpeed"].ToString();

        lblCurrentClockSpeed.Text = "";
        lblCurrentClockSpeed.Text = clockSpeed;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

I got it working :)

Hereby my code fragments:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateAndStartTimer();
}

private async void CreateAndStartTimer()
{
    // Create an AutoResetEvent to signal the timeout threshold in the
    // timer callback has been reached.
    var autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    await Task.Run(() => new System.Threading.Timer(GetCurrentCpuClockSpeed, autoEvent, 1000, 1000));

}

private void GetCurrentCpuClockSpeed(object sender)
{
    bool isCallerOnDifferentThread = lblCurrentClockSpeed.InvokeRequired;

    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");

    foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get()) {
        var clockSpeed = obj["CurrentClockSpeed"].ToString();

        if (isCallerOnDifferentThread) {
            lblCurrentClockSpeed.Invoke(new Action(() => { lblCurrentClockSpeed.Text = clockSpeed; }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a very convoluted alternative to using a timer... Your approach consumes a single thread, a timer does not.

Comment: @canton7: Thank you for your reply! I thought a Backgroundworker does its work on a separate thread, so I do not 'harm' the UI. That's why I choose this approach.

Comment: `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` is called on a separate thread, but all it does is sleep that thread and call `ReportProgress` every so often. `GetCurrentCpuSpeed` is still called on the main thread. A Timer which calls `GetCurrentCpuSpeed` would do exactly the same thing, but without grabbing an entire thread only to sleep it

Comment: Timer does not harm or halt the UI thread.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to contain updated code

Comment: How long does the UI freeze for? Is it simply that the code in `GetCurrentCpuClockSpeed` takes a few seconds to run?

Comment: Ah, the actual freezes takes about 0,5 to 1 seconds or so. So maybe it's indeed the GetCurrentCpuSpeed2-method that causes the freeze. But if I change the timer interval to 1000 (1 second) the complete program freezes completely. Ideally I want to get the CurrentClockSpeed directly and not use a for-each. Just like in a 'normal' list; if you know what you want you could do: myList.firstOrDefault(x => x.name == "CurrentClockSpeed"). But that is not possible in this case I think?

Comment: A couple of suggestions: - since you just need the `CurrentClockSpeed`, query just that instead of  `SELECT * FROM ...` - The Management query object can be configured with an `EnumerationOptions` object, which provides the `Rewindable`, `ReturnImmediately`, `DirectRead` and `EnumerateDeep` properties. These, when set correctly (e.g., `Rewindable = false`, `ReturnImmediately = true`, `DirectRead = true`, `EnumerateDeep =  false`), can speed up the process.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @Jimi!

Comment: For unknown reasons, I linked `System.Management.Instrumentation`, totally unrelated, instead of `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure`. Now corrected.

Comment: @DevDon - Please don't post your working code in your question. Please post it as an answer. Your question should be a clear cut question only.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wmi_v2/mi-managed-api/hh832958(v=vs.85)) (aka WMI V2, you need to install a [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure/)), instead of [System.Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management) (you can use it anyway, but it's *slower*), querying [Win32_Processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-processor) for just **`CurrentClockSpeed`**.

I think the time required to return the query value is acceptable to use a non-threaded Timer ([System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer), here).

In a not-so-great test machine, (I5-4690K, 16GB, no SSD), the query returs in `0` to `27` milliseconds.

Give it a shot:

Here, **`lblCpuClock`** is the name assigned to the Label that receives the CPU Clock value.

Here, the Timer is initialized in the Form constructor, started when the Form is Shown and stopped when the Form closes.
If you you need to start it at some other time, don't use a Lambda to subscribe to the `Tick` event (`cpuClockTimer.Tick += (s, e) => { ... }`), use a proper method handler and unsubscribe from the event when you stop the Timer
.

```
public partial class SomeForm : Form
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer cpuClockTimer = null;

    public SomeForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // [...]

        if (this.components == null) this.components = new Container();
        cpuClockTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components) { Interval = 1000 };

        cpuClockTimer.Tick += (s, e) => {
            uint? result = InfrastructureQueries.GetCurrentCpuClock(null);
            if (result.HasValue && !lblCpuClock.IsDisposed) {
                lblCpuClock.Text = $"Clock Speed: {result.Value} MHz";
            }
        };
    }

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnShown(e);
        cpuClockTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        cpuClockTimer.Enabled = false;
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, try to start a Task and see whether it's a better fit.

*As mentioned (in comments now in *deleted* state), you can use use a BackgroundWorker, but of course, don't reference Controls created in the UI Thread from the method that performs the query; that method just needs to return a value that you can then pass to the `ProgressChanged` event handler when you raise the event.

That event is raised in the UI Thread, so you can safely access your Controls from the handler.*

Here, the Task is run when the Form is shown (int the `OnShown` override).
Move `Task.Run(() => UpdateCpuClock(...)` in another method if you want to run it *on-demand* instead.

Use `ctsCpuClock.Cancel();` to cancel the Task at any time.

```
public partial class SomeForm : Form
{
    static CancellationTokenSource ctsCpuClock = null;
    Progress<uint> ClockProgress = null;

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnShown(e);
        ctsCpuClock = new CancellationTokenSource();
        clockProgress = new Progress<uint>(value => {
            if (!lblCpuClock.IsDisposed) {
                lblCpuClock.Text = $"Clock Speed: {value} MHz";
            }
        });
        Task.Run(() => UpdateCpuClock(clockProgress, ctsCpuClock.Token));
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        ctsCpuClock?.Cancel();
        ctsCpuClock?.Dispose();
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }

    private async Task UpdateCpuClock(IProgress<uint> progress, CancellationToken token) {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested) {
            uint? result = InfrastructureQueries.GetCurrentCpuClock(null);
            if (result.HasValue) {
                progress.Report(result.Value);
            }
            try { await Task.Delay(1000, token); }
            // Handle if you need logging, otherwise let go: your code called Cancel()
            catch (TaskCanceledException) { break; }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**`Management.Infrastructure` worker methods**:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure;

public class InfrastructureQueries
{
    private const string nameSpace = @"root\cimv2";

    private static CimSession CreateSession(string computerName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(computerName) || 
            computerName.Equals("localhost", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
            computerName = null;
        }
        return CimSession.Create(computerName);
    }

    public static uint? GetCurrentCpuClock(string computerName = null)
    {
        var session = CreateSession(computerName);
        IEnumerable<CimInstance> query = session.QueryInstances(
            nameSpace, "WQL", "SELECT CurrentClockSpeed FROM Win32_Processor");

        return (uint?)query.FirstOrDefault()?.CimInstanceProperties["CurrentClockSpeed"].Value;
    }
}
```